# Ensure a value is in a set, and set a default if it isn't

Tags: ruby

I am doing something like this to check if a parameter is in a set, and set a default value if it is not. It looks unnecessarily wordy:

```
allowed_types = [:poem, :product, :news, :facebook, :tweet]
@type = params[:type]
@type = :poem unless allowed_types.include?(@type)
```

What is the most Ruby way to accomplish this?

Comment: are you interested in creating new abstractions? this is one I use: `@type = params[:type].whitelist(allowed_types) || :poem`.

Comment: @tokland Now see my one! How is it? :)

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
allowed_types = [:poem, :product, :news, :facebook, :tweet]
@type = allowed_types.include?(params[:type]) ? params[:type] : :poem
```

---

Seen that we're here, I would say that IMHO it would be useful an Array method similar to `Hash#fetch`; something like:

```
class Array
  # `fetch` is already taken (index fetching)
  def fetch_value(something, ifnone = nil)
    include?(something) ? something : ifnone
  end
end

[:poem, :product, :news].fetch_value(:news, :poem) #=> :news
[:poem, :product, :news].fetch_value(:salad, :poem) #=> :poem
```

So someone could do:

```
@type = allowed_types.fetch_value(params[:type], :poem)
```

Comment: StackOverflow implements a real-time syntax errors checking: it is called @Mischa =)

Comment: To be honest it looks complicated. include! looks like you want to do any kind of things for the array instead of checking the value in array. it's better to use fetch method of Hash.

Comment: @oivoodoo I agree that `include!` is a bad name (maybe `Array#fetch_value`?), but I don't agree that `fetch` is a good solution: `Array#fetch` looks for indexes, and mapping an array to an hash just in order to use `Hash#fetch` is poor IMHO

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify it like this:

```
allowed_types = [:poem, :product, :news, :facebook, :tweet]
@type = allowed_types.include?(params[:type]) ? params[:type] : :poem
```

But what you really should be doing is validations, try to keep all the logic there. Perhaps something like:

```
validates :type, inclusion: { in:  %w(poem product news facebook tweet) }
```

For the `params` I assume you are in rails or synatra.

Comment: I'll be validating too, but I also want to do this: send(:"new_#{@type}"), and don't want to risk a url attack.

Comment: Now see my one! How is it? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2,4,5]
var = a.detect(proc{"not present"}){ |x| x == 55 }
p var #=> "not present"

a = [1,2,4,5]
var = a.detect(proc{"not present"}){ |x| x == 4 }
p var #=> 4

a = [1,2,4,5]
var = a.detect(proc{"not present"}){ |x| x == 1 }
p var #=> 1
```

Comment: @ProGNOMmers I have changed my idea. :)

Comment: Good! I like the `detect` solution too, it is a good use of `Enumerable` module. I can delete my comment :)

Comment: @ProGNOMmers Thank you very much :) I always care others comments. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this in the model:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
   ALLOWED_TYPES = Hash[[:poem, :product, :news, :facebook, :tweet].map{|v| [v,v]}] # { :poem => :poem ...
end
```

in the controller you can use fetch method for the ALLOWED_TYPES:

```
ModelName::ALLOWED_TYPES.fetch(params[:type], :poem) # it will set as default poem
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an identity hash and [`Hash#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

```
allowed_types = Hash[ [:poem, :product, :news, :facebook, :tweet].map{|e| [e,e]} ]
@type = allowed_types.fetch(@type, :poem)
```